# How to receive root cause for Pipeline Dataflow job failure

Tags: error-handling, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am running my pipeline in Dataflow. I want to collect all error messages from Dataflow job using its id. I am using Apache-beam 2.3.0 and Java 8.

```java
DataflowPipelineJob dataflowPipelineJob = ((DataflowPipelineJob) entry.getValue());
String jobId = dataflowPipelineJob.getJobId();
DataflowClient client = DataflowClient.create(options);
Job job = client.getJob(jobId);
```

Is there any way to receive only error message from pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Programmatic support for reading Dataflow log messages is not very mature, but there are a couple options:

1. Since you already have the `DataflowPipelineJob` instance, you could use the [`waitUntilFinish()`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/DataflowPipelineJob.html#waitUntilFinish-org.joda.time.Duration-org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.MonitoringUtil.JobMessagesHandler-) overload which accepts a [`JobMessagesHandler`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/util/MonitoringUtil.JobMessagesHandler.html) parameter to filter and capture error messages. You can see how `DataflowPipelineJob` uses this in its own [`waitUntilFinish()`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/ae2e12ac3c7dcc3831b185407853331f5d383e0c/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/DataflowPipelineJob.java#L200) implementation.
2. Alternatively, you can query job logs using the Dataflow REST API: [`projects.jobs.messages/list`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs.messages/list). The API takes in a `minimumImportance` parameter which would allow you to query just for errors.

Note that in both cases, there may be error messages which are not fatal and don't directly cause job failure.